# Format money for display: "x" -> "x.00"?

Tags: php

I am storing money in MySQL with float format but `.00` are removed since they don't have much meaning but I want to show them to user in a correct money format using PHP.

I wrote a function which checks whether the money field has any `.` period otherwise add `.00`.

But personally I didn't like this function so I am looking for a built-in function which can do the same job:

```
function formatMoney($price){
    if (strpos($price,".") > -1)
        return $price;
    else
        return $price . ".00";
}
```

**Edit:** For the people who somehow reached my question should know that `money_format` doesn't work on Windows Machines as it is explained here below taken from the PHP Manual:

> The function money_format() is only defined if the system has strfmon
>   capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so money_format() is
>   undefined in Windows.

So you should use `number_format` in place of it. You can see my answer on how I solved this problem.

Comment: What if `$price` is `1.2` or `1.234` (or `2.0/3`)? Also, what is the expected type of `$price`? You may also being promoting a number to a string silently! None of these sounds good.

Comment: (The issue with the silent promotion is now the return type might be the-type-of-$price or the-type-of-a-string: it should likely *alway* be a string.)

Comment: Just FYI, floats aren't a good format for storing money values as they are subject to rounding errors.  You're better off using decimal instead (which implements fixed-point decimal numbers that are immune to rounding errors, provided all the maths is done by the SQL server at least).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems money_format doesn't work on Windows machines then I had to use `number_format($price,2)` and it worked just perfect.

Note from PHP Manual:

> The function `money_format()` is only defined if the system has strfmon
>   capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so money_format() is
>   undefined in Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use [`money_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)?

Example:

```
$price = 43;
money_format('%.2n', $price);
```

Comment: Well it seems `money_format` doesn't work on Windows machines.

Answer (score 0):

Use [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) or [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

Comment: sprintf will drop the resulting string into another variable, not print it to STDOUT.

Comment: And the example code offered by OP returns a value, doesn't put it on stdout.